# Is this a general form for the confidence interval of a uniform distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, parameter-estimation, confidence-interval

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ a random sample with $X_i \sim \mathcal{U}[0,
    \theta]$ (where $\mathcal{U}$ = uniform dist). Let $Y = \max(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$, the MLE of $\theta$. It
can be proven that $U = \frac{Y}{\theta}$ has density

\begin{align*}
    f_U(u) = \begin{cases}
        n u^{n-1} & 0 \leq u \leq 1 \\ 
        0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

Evidently, $P(A \leq \frac{Y}{\theta} \leq B)$ is given by

\begin{align*}
F_U(B) - F_U(A)
\end{align*}

Then, if $\mathcal{P}(A, B) := P(A \leq \frac{Y}{\theta} \leq B)$, we have

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{P}(A, B) 
&= n \left[\int_0^{B}  u^{n-1} ~ du - \int_0^{A} u^{n-1}
\right] \\ 
&= n \left[ \frac{B^n}{n} - \frac{A^n}{n} \right]  \\ 
&= B^n - A^n
\end{align*}

From this follows that $\mathcal{P}(\alpha^{\frac{1}{n}}, 1) = 1 - \alpha$. I want to use this to form confidence intervals for $\theta$, but I am unsure about whether my procedure to do this is correct. It takes simple manipulations to show that

\begin{align*}
P(\alpha^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq \frac{Y}{\theta} \leq 1) = P( Y \leq \theta \leq
\frac{Y}{\alpha^{\frac{1}{n}}}) = 1 - \alpha
\end{align*}

Thus, the expression seems to serve to produce the CI $[Y, Y
\alpha^{-\frac{1}{n}}]$ with confidence $1-\alpha$. For example, for $\alpha = 1/2
$, we have that $\theta$ will belong to $[Y, \frac{Y}{2^{\frac{1}{n}}}]$.
Since $2^{\frac{1}{n}} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, with $n$
sufficiently large this means $\theta \in [Y, Y + \epsilon]$ for a very marginal
$\epsilon$, with probability $95\%$.

Is this correct? If not, how can one use the derivations presented to form confidence intervals for the real value of $\theta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivation seems correct except that you wrote $2^{\frac1n}$ instead of $\left(\frac12\right)^{\frac1n}$. The conclusion is correct, though: The more data you have, the closer the maximum is likely to be to $\theta$, and thus the narrower the interval you need for $95\%$ confidence.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to review this!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, **to reach the conclusion** that a confidence interval involving the maximum order statistic $Y_n$ (the ML estimator of $\theta$) of the form $\color{blue}{\left (Y_n, Y_n+\epsilon  \right)}$ is the best one, **we need more work** because one can construct different types of confidence intervals based on $Y_n$.

As $$\frac{Y_n}{\theta} \sim Beta(n,1),$$

we have for any $\beta \in [0,1]$

$$\mathbb P \left ( b_{1-\alpha (1-\beta)} \le \frac{Y_n}{\theta} \le b_{\alpha \beta } \right)=1-\alpha$$

where for any $w \in [0,1]$, $b_w$ denotes the upper $w$ percentile of $Beta(n,1)$, defined as

$$F_{Beta(n,1)}(b_w)=1-w.$$

Considering $F_{Beta(n,1)}(x)=x^n$ for $0 \le x \le 1$,

$$b_{\alpha \beta}=\left(1-\alpha \beta \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

$$b_{1-\alpha (1-\beta)}=\left(\alpha (1-\beta) \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}.$$

Hence, we obtain the following confidence interval:

$$\left ( \frac{Y_n}{\left(1-\alpha \beta \right)^{\frac{1}{n}} }, \frac{Y_n}{\left( \alpha (1-\beta) \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}} \right).$$

For $\beta=0, \frac{1}{2}, 1,$ we get the following confidence intervals:

$$\left ( Y_n , \frac{Y_n}{\alpha ^{\frac{1}{n}}} \right)$$

$$\left ( \frac{Y_n}{\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}}, \frac{Y_n}{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}} \right),$$

$$\left ( \frac{Y_n}{\left(1-\alpha \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}}, \infty \right)$$

These are of the forms $\color{blue}{\left (Y_n, Y_n+\epsilon  \right)}$, $\color{blue}{\left (Y_n+\epsilon_1, Y_n+\epsilon_2  \right)}$, and $\color{blue}{\left (Y_n+\epsilon, \infty \right)}$, respectively.

The parameter $\beta$ is often set in a way that the expected length of the confidence interval:

$$\mathbb E(Y_n) \left [ \left( \alpha (1-\beta) \right)^{-\frac{1}{n}} - \left(1-\alpha \beta \right)^{-\frac{1}{n}}  \right ],$$

is minimized. Following this approach and considering that the above is increasing in $\beta$ (the derivative is negative), $\beta=0$ is the global minimizer, and thus $\color{blue}{\left (Y_n, Y_n+\epsilon  \right)}$ is the most preferred interval.

Comment: Your point, if I follow, is that the interval I provided is not the unique confidence interval that surrounds the population value. I reckon that many other confidence intervals may be produced. How does this affect the accuracy of my conclusion?

Thanks for the response.

Comment: The lower boundary of these intervals is also of the form $(Y+\epsilon_1)$. It wouldn’t make sense if it were $-\epsilon_1$, since the parameter can’t be less than the maximum; and indeed dividing by $b_w\le1$ increases $Y$. Also, note that you can do this more generally by dividing $\alpha$ into two non-negative parts, $\lambda$ and $\alpha-\lambda$, and constructing

$$
\left[\frac Y{\left(1-\lambda\right)^{\frac1n}},\frac Y{\left(\alpha-\lambda\right)^{\frac1n}}\right]\;.
$$

Comment: Then $\lambda=0$ yields the interval in the question, and $\lambda=\frac\alpha2$ and $\lambda=\alpha$ yield your other intervals. The length of the interval is minimal for $\lambda=0$, so the approach in the question would usually be the preferred one. (@lafinur)

Comment: @lafinur I tried to improve my answer.  My point is that more work needs to get your conclusion.

Comment: @joriki I Thanks for your comments. I tried to improve the answer.